# non-member operator in Cython

Tags: cython

I'm currently doing a Cython wrapper for an existing C++ library. I have an overloaded non-member operator in C++ like

```
Data operator+(Data const& a, Data const& b)
```

And in the `pxd` file describing the header, I wrote

```
cdef extern from 'blabla.h':
    Data operator+(const Data&, const Data&)
```

Now how can I use this `operator+` in another `pyx` file?

Comment: `include "your_pxd.pxd"` in your .pyx doesn't work for that?

Comment: @CristiánAntuña well I have to rename this operator to something else and call it as a normal function. I want to use `+` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For very simple cases, like in your example you can lie to Cython and tell it that the operator is a member function:

```
cdef extern from 'blabla.h':
  cdef cppclass Data:
    # the rest of the data definitions
    Data operator+(const Data&)
```

It only uses this information to know that it can translate the code `a+b` (where `a` and `b` are data objects) to `__pyx_v_a + __pyx_v_b` and let the c++ compiler do the rest (which it knows how to because of the import from "blabla.h"). Therefore, the distinction between member and non-member is irrelevant.

*However*: one of the main reasons to use nonmember operators is to allow things like

```
Data operator+(int a, const Data& b);
```

You can make this work, but it's very slightly messy. In your pxd file do

```
cdef extern from 'blabla.h':
    Data operator+(int, const Data&) # i.e. do nothing special
```

In your pyx file

```
from my_pxd_file import * # works fine
## but this isn't accepted unfortunately:
from my_pxd_file import operator+
```

If you wanted to avoid too much namespace pollution from doing `import *`, you could probably create a pxd file that only contains operators and not the class definitions (I haven't tested this though)

In conclusion - two methods depending on how complicated your use-case is...