# Cython: counter-tutorial behavior

Tags: python, c++, templates, operator-overloading, cython

[Tutorial](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html) says `.pyx` and `.pxd` files should not have the same name unless `.pyx` is the realization of the definitions from `.pxd` file.

> Note that the name of the .pyx file must be different from the
>   cqueue.pxd file with declarations from the C library, as both do not
>   describe the same code. A .pxd file next to a .pyx file with the same
>   name defines exported declarations for code in the .pyx file. As the
>   cqueue.pxd file contains declarations of a regular C library, there
>   must not be a .pyx file with the same name that Cython associates with
>   it.

Yet I ran into a situation when it works properly only when the same name is given to those two files even though `.pxd` is `cdef extern` cpp declaration unrelated to `.pyx` code.

py_test.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from py_test cimport Test

def f():
    Test[double](2.) + 3.
```

zzz.pyx:

```
# distutils: language = c++

from py_test cimport Test

def f():
    Test[double](2.) + 3.
```

py_test.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "cpp_test.h": 
    cdef cppclass Test[T]:
        Test()
        Test(T value)
        T value
    cdef Test[T] operator+[T](Test[T]&, T)
```

cpp_test.h:

```
template<typename T>
class Test { 
public: 
    T value; 
    Test():value(0){}
    Test(T value):value(value){}
    ~Test(){}
};

template<typename T>
Test<T> operator+(const Test<T>& x, T y) {
    return Test<T>(x.value + y);
}
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = "demo",  # unused
#   ext_modules = cythonize('py_test.pyx'), # ok
    ext_modules = cythonize('zzz.pyx'), # Invalid operand types for '+' (Test[double]; double) 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the tutorial says that the .pyx and .pxd files should not have the same name is that a .pyx file will automatically do the equivalent of `from pxd_file_with_the_same_name cimport *` if it finds a file with the same name.

So the reason to avoid having unrelated files with the same name is just to avoid confusing behaviour where something gets `cimport`ed that you don't expect.

---

This specific case has to do with how Cython imports non-member C++ operators which is frankly a bit buggy. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732524/non-member-operator-in-cython).

The non-member operator will only be available to Cython if it's `cimport`ed into the current module scope (i.e. just importing the associated class won't do it). Unfortunately there's no way to `cimport` it directly that I know of, but if you change `zzz.pyx` to start with

```
from py_test cimport *
```

then the `*` *does* managed to `cimport` the operator and it should work. Because `py_test.pyx` does this implicitly then it works without further changes.

---

(With respect to your [previous question about complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038496/cython-error-adding-complexdouble-to-double) which motivated this I tried messing around with this kind of idea and couldn't immediately get it to work, but perhaps you'll have more luck than me)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! I know another way of cimporting `operator+` though (see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of cimporting `operator+` is like this:

zzz.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++

from py_test cimport Test, add

def f():
    add(Test[double](2.), 3.)
```

pytest.pxd:

```
cdef extern from "cpp_test.h": 
    cdef cppclass Test[T]:
        Test()
        Test(T value)
        T value
    cdef Test[T] add "operator+"[T](Test[T]&, T)
```

In certain cases it might be preferable over `cimport *`, yet it is not ideal as it alters the semantics of the operator invocation.